# Explain precisely why a sequence is (not) continuous and differentiable.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

> Explain precisely why sequence $a_n = n $ is (not) continuous and
>   differentiable.

I have given this problem some thought and come up with the following answer: A sequence is continuous but is not differentiable.

**Continuous:**
Consider a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x) = x$. Now consider $f \upharpoonright \mathbb N$ This is exactly the sequence in question and it's continuous because if we restrict the domain of a continuous function ($f(x) = x$) then the resulting function is still continuous. 
**Not differentiable:**
We are only allowed to take the differential quotient in some neighborhood of a limit point of the domain of the function. Since the domain of our sequence has no limit points, it cannot be differentiable. 
 
Do you think that my explanation is satisfactory?

Comment: The continuity of any function depends on what topology/metric you have on domain and codomain. Thus the question about continuity cannot be answered. But you are right about differentiability. Although I would simply say "no generally known and accepted concept of differentiability applies to sequences". Because the definition you are refering to in your answer is one of many possible.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem you asked is the one you mean to ask.  A (real) *sequence* is a mapping from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$, but there isn't a definition of what a "derivative" of this mapping is.  Given a topology on both the domain $\mathbb N$ and codomain $\mathbb R$, it does make sense to ask if the mapping is *continuous*.  However the usual topology on the natural numbers (the one inherited from the real topology (metric)) is *discrete* (and thus the mapping is continuous however your sequence $\{a_n\}$ is constructed).

Comment: Over which metric space has it been defined? $\Bbb Q $ or $\Bbb N $ or $\Bbb R $?

Comment: Over $\mathbb R$